# Remove all js from template

Tags: 6, javascript, theming

I'm trying to remove all javascript for anonymous users but I've hit a roadblock.

This is the php I'm using in template.php (phptemplate_preprocess_page function):

```
$js = drupal_add_js();
unset($js['core']);
unset($js['module']);
unset($js['setting']);

$vars['scripts'] = $js;

print_r($vars['scripts']); // prints what it should
print_r(drupal_add_js('header', $js));  // prints everything like nothing happened!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. It seems that the JQuery Update module is the culprit, more specifically the jquery_update_theme_registry_alter function:

- Make jQuery Update's page preprocess function run *after* everything else's,
- so that a theme can't call drupal_get_js() and mess everything up.
  */

I will discuss this with the Jquery update module makers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in function phptemplate_preprocess_page exists in template.php

The below is code to remove unwanted js

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  $scripts = drupal_add_js();
  //PRINT THIS ARRAY AND UNSET THE UNWANTED ARRAY
  // unset($scripts['module']['sites/default/files/js/jquery-min.js']);
  unset($scripts['module']['YOUR_PATH_TO_JS']);
  $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);  

}
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I already have that in that function.

Comment: ok, then it should work! Did you enabled page cache or js aggregation?

Comment: Cache and aggregation is disabled. It definitely should work so any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Ok, check in your page.tpl.php print $scripts; present or not.Then Clear your cache again.Check that , drupal is calling this function or not?

Comment: It is printing $scripts normally and I've tried clearing the cache several times. And yes, Drupal is calling the script. I'm beginning to think this is quite strange.