# $scripts variable in drupal 6 adding unwanted script codes

Tags: theming, javascript

From where does the $scripts variable in drupal gets generated? I am getting an unwanted code generated in the html code like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js_01770598d5388f7cbcfe786a6df4ef2a.js"></script>
```

I want to remove that code, for that I need to know the details about $scripts varialble used in tpl file

Comment: imho you need to be certain that the included js is actually unwanted before deciding to remove it, it might be any of the contributed modules that your site uses and could paralyze some functionality. If you are certain that the script is useless you could check [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30741/how-to-unset-javascripts-in-drupal) and [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23944/remove-all-js-from-template) to aid your cause.

Comment: no, it is a malware

Comment: It it actually in the rendered output when you do a view source, or is it being dynamically added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start at [`template_preprocess_node()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6) where the `$scripts` variable is initialised:

```
$variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
```

Then have a look at [`drupal_get_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_js/6) and follow the functions from there to find out how that mechanism works.

Then have a look at any implementations of `hook_page_alter()` throughout your site, where the `$vars['scripts']` variable might be being manipulated.

Even though that technically answers your question, I'd be surprised if you find what you're looking for there. I've never heard of any malware that specifically targets Drupal (which is what this would be if it's manipulating the `$scripts` variable).

I'd check the rest of your page source to see if there's some JS being injected somewhere which is adding that `<script>` tag to the `<head>` dynamically, just in case.